# I accidently sent ETH to the contract address instead of the funding address

Tags: ether, ico

I'm hoping for reassurance that my ETH is not lost. I attempted to contribute to an ICO but instead of sending the ETH to the contribution address, I sent it to the contract which all the contributions were eventually sent to from the contribution address.

The tx hash is 
[0x7a3fb9d8fc2e18d702f4ea236ec3793a5aa7f9389020295a71cdbb973b870bda](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7a3fb9d8fc2e18d702f4ea236ec3793a5aa7f9389020295a71cdbb973b870bda)

I sent the ether to contract [0x05A9aFD79a05C3e1AFEFa282Ef8d58F9366B160B](https://etherscan.io/address/0x05a9afd79a05c3e1afefa282ef8d58f9366b160b)

Instead of the contribution address 0xe3818504c1B32bF1557b16C238B2E01Fd3149C17

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: They are not lost, the destination it is a multisigwallet, but you should get in contact with the team right now, and ask them if they can refund you ethers so you can contribute to the crowdsale before it is over.

Comment: Very much appreciated. In fact I attempted to contact them before posting the question but did not get a reply as of yet. I am not savvy of how smart contracts are structured and wanted to make sure my Ether is not lost.

Comment: @Zimzeemer were you able to get back ETH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the owner of the multisig and ask for a refund. Expect it to take days/weeks since they are probably in the middle of an ICO.

I think if the team is honest (which they should be) It should be pretty safe to assume they can send the 21 Eth back.

Comment: Thank you. The ICO will wrap up by tomorrow. The devs are well known and respected in the space. I hope to get the refund in time and contribute to the ICO.

Comment: Hey @Zimzeemer - it looks like that 21 ETH is still stuck in the contract. Does sending to the contract itself effectively destroy the ETH? That is my suspicion.